# Unable to install packages on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, networking, apt, virtualbox

I am trying to install ROS-Bridge suite on my Linux machine. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Virtualbox based Linux VM. Whenever I write this command

```
sudo apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server
```

It says:

```
unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080.
```

The strange thing is that i can not open this IP address on a web browser. The ROS packages can be opened manually through the browser. Then i tried to use `sudo apt-get update` and it still shows the same error.

I do not understand why it always tries to connect to this address. I have also changed my mode of Internet connection but I always have the same problem.

EDIT 1 :
I follow the instructions [here](https://roslibpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#ros-setup). I have already installed ROS on this machine.

EDIT 2 : I looked in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, there are some files but none of them contains this IP address. However there is a file called `ros-latest.list` which contains this `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main`

Here is the exact output on the console :

```
aakash@aakash-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server
[sudo] password for aakash: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37 linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-38 linux-headers-4.13.0-38-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-39 linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-backports.ssl-match-hostname python-bson python-bson-ext
  python-pycurl python-pymysql python-tornado ros-kinetic-rosapi
  ros-kinetic-rosauth ros-kinetic-rosbridge-library
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg python-pycurl-doc python-pymysql-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-backports.ssl-match-hostname python-bson python-bson-ext
  python-pycurl python-pymysql python-tornado ros-kinetic-rosapi
  ros-kinetic-rosauth ros-kinetic-rosbridge-library
  ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 311 not upgraded.
Need to get 666 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5.391 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 python-pymysql all 0.7.2-1ubuntu1
Ign:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 python-backports.ssl-match-hostname all 3.4.0.2-1
Err:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-bson amd64 3.2-1build1
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-bson-ext amd64 3.2-1build1
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-pycurl amd64 7.43.0-1ubuntu1
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-tornado amd64 4.2.1-1ubuntu3
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rosbridge-library amd64 0.9.0-0xenial-20180408-180804-0800
  Could not connect to 10.16.79.1:8080 (10.16.79.1), connection timed out
Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rosapi amd64 0.9.0-0xenial-20180408-181428-0800
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rosauth amd64 0.1.7-0xenial-20180222-225110-0800
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:10 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server amd64 0.9.0-0xenial-20180408-181645-0800
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
Err:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 python-pymysql all 0.7.2-1ubuntu1
  Could not connect to 10.16.79.1:8080 (10.16.79.1), connection timed out
Err:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 python-backports.ssl-match-hostname all 3.4.0.2-1
  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-pymysql/python-pymysql_0.7.2-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Could not connect to 10.16.79.1:8080 (10.16.79.1), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/backports.ssl-match-hostname/python-backports.ssl-match-hostname_3.4.0.2-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pymongo/python-bson_3.2-1build1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pymongo/python-bson-ext_3.2-1build1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pycurl/python-pycurl_7.43.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-tornado/python-tornado_4.2.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rosbridge-library/ros-kinetic-rosbridge-library_0.9.0-0xenial-20180408-180804-0800_amd64.deb  Could not connect to 10.16.79.1:8080 (10.16.79.1), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rosapi/ros-kinetic-rosapi_0.9.0-0xenial-20180408-181428-0800_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rosauth/ros-kinetic-rosauth_0.1.7-0xenial-20180222-225110-0800_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server/ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server_0.9.0-0xenial-20180408-181645-0800_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 10.16.79.1:8080:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Could you [edit] your question and post the full output of the mentioned command? Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). You should also check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (if any) whether they contain this address. If they do, follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed.

Comment: the package you try to install is not in the standard repositories. Please add the steps you have taken before trying to install it.

Comment: @RoVo .. When have trying to install a package not in the repositories, started to give `unable to connect to .........` - it looks more like a repository not reachable / not answering.

Comment: Take a look at the IP address: 10.*.*.* addresses are either your LAN or your VM host network adapter. Does not seem like an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Yes my host adapter IP address is in this range. but the problem is I have even connected it to my mobile data...but still it tries to reach the same address.

Comment: Do you use a proxy server? Please check whether you can `ping de.archive.ubuntu.com` and whether the IP address `10.16.79.1` appears in `traceroute de.archive.ubuntu.com`.